# Lucene query with phrase order slop and OR clause

Tags: java, lucene

I need to frame a lucene query such that it works for both "convert int to string" and "convert integer to string". Also, in the matched results, there could be more words in between the terms. For example "How could I convert a proper int to a well formatted string". I tried the following:

```
Query query = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {
                new SpanTermQuery(new Term("title", "convert")),
                new SpanTermQuery(new Term("title", "int")),
                new SpanTermQuery(new Term("title", "string"))
              },
              50,
              true);        
    return query;
```

and the following:

```
MultiPhraseQuery mpq = new MultiPhraseQuery();
    mpq.setSlop(50);
    mpq.add(new Term("title","convert"));       
    mpq.add(new Term[]{new Term("title","int"),new Term("title", "integer")});        
    mpq.add(new Term("title","string"));            
    return mpq;
```

and also the following:

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();           
    bq.add(new TermQuery(new Term("title","convert")), Occur.MUST);
    BooleanQuery idFilter = new BooleanQuery();
    idFilter.setMinimumNumberShouldMatch(1);
    idFilter.add(new TermQuery(new Term("title", "int")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    idFilter.add(new TermQuery(new Term("title", "integer")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);          
    bq.add(idFilter, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    bq.add(new TermQuery(new Term("title","string")), Occur.MUST);
    return bq;
```

None of them seem to do what I need. Can someone help me write a valid query which includes both order of terms and also allows to specify "OR" condition? Thanks.

Comment: Your two first attempts look good and should have worked. But as everything depends on the analyzer, you should open your index with the [Luke tool](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke) to see how it has been analyzed. This will give you more clues as to what's wrong.

Comment: In the first attempt, I don't see a way to mention "OR" for int/integer. In the second attempt, order is ignored.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the question. And yes, in the second case the order is ignored because of the slop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt is closest to the mark.  The stumbling block there is how to handle int vs integer.

Two approaches for this come to mind.  The best approach might be to incorporate a `SynonymFilter` into your analyzer.  This would allow you to set up a synonym automatically converting `integer` to `int` at index time, reducing the need to come up with more complex querying logic.

As far as setting it up strictly in the query construction, I don't know of a way to wrap a boolean query into a span query, but a wildcard, or more precisely, a prefix, query seems like it would serve that purpose, which can be used in a `SpanNearQuery` by wrapping it in a [`SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper.html), something like:

```
Query query = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {
         new SpanTermQuery(new Term("title", "convert")),
         new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new PrefixQuery(new Term("title", "int"))),
         new SpanTermQuery(new Term("title", "string"))
     },
     50,
     true);
return query;
```

`int*` may not be quite identical to `int OR integer`, but hopefully it's close enough.